# Understanding how an XML is structured

Tags: java, xml

I understand that xml documents are made up of roots,parents,children,grandchildren and even leaf nodes.
I have a big xml file and I am not 100% on whether or not I am correct in thinking that the depth of an xml files structure goes:

parent,child,grandchild

**or**

parent,child,leaf

Below is a sample of the xml file, I have tried searching for other answers on Stack relating to xml structures however I have not found anything that I feel relates to how my file structure is.

Having the DefEnv tag and then the Environment tag underneath is what confuses me on the structure.
Is the root classed as being the same as the parent. If defEnv is classed as the parent does that make environment the child with element content?

```
<DefEnv id="FFT">           //parent?
     <Environment id="Test">  //child?

        <DB id="DDM">
            <JdbcDriver>driver</JdbcDriver>
            <jdbcURL>URL</jdbcURL>          
            <ConPoolmaxConnections>20</ConPoolmaxConnections>



            <DriverProperties>
                <Property>
                <Key>prompt</Key>
                <Value>false</Value> 
        </DriverProperties>
        </DB>
    </Environment>
<DefEnv>
```

Comment: Are you asking whether XML has a specific depth of children that's permitted?

Comment: If one tag is nested inside another, then it's a child element. In your case DefEnv is parent and Environment is its child. DefEnv is in fact the root element. You might be confused why DefEnv is not the child of Environment, but other way around here, but that's not your concern. That's the structure so you gotta parse it the way it is. You don't need to make logical sense of which element needs to be child of what other element.

Comment: Is your XML complete, you're missing closing tags? as regards parent/child, everything is relative. DefEnv is root and parent to Environment. jdbcURL is child of DB etc.

Comment: Also, what classes/technologies are you using to parse/handle your XML?

Comment: Thanks for the replies
@neo thankyou for explaining my structure

Comment: @TedTrippin - I was going to use DOM but I have already read my file for the environment id using bufferedreader/filereader. Could I use that instead? Thank you for pointing out that I had misses a closing tag off I have fixed that. I was just using a section of it as an example

Comment: Most people don't like vague questions I advise you follow the [oracle DOM tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/dom) then ask a specific question

Comment: I am just using DOM sorry for the confusion but I can't edit the comment. In order to remove the child element environment is it correct to first retrieve the parent (in my case DefEnv)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If one tag is nested inside another, then it's a child element. In your case DefEnv is parent and Environment is its child. DefEnv is in fact the root element. You might be confused why DefEnv is not the child of Environment, but other way around here, but that's not your concern. That's the structure so you gotta parse it the way it is. You don't need to make logical sense of which element needs to be child of what other element. For example XHTML is based on xml. In that case, you have to care about things like html tag needs to be the root element and body tag needs to be the child element. In your case, you don't care because you just want to parse the id attribute of Environment. You can use XPath or Xslt to get the id. Research on them.

Answer (score -1):

The notion of Parent and Child id relative of the element you are using.

In fact, your element "Evironement" is the child of DefEnv, but is also the parent of "DB" while DB is the child of Environement.

A leaf is simply an element without any child.

Comment: How does that help get the Environment ID?